# C++ Make a Char Array have a Value of the string

Tags: c++, arrays, class, char

For my program, I have a highscore section. I get the input with a string, but how can I now make the string equal into a char array? FYI: The string `playersName` will already be filled out with a name. Here is my code:

```
class Highscore
{
    public:
        char name[10];
        ...[Code]...
}

...[Code]...
// Declare variables *The playersName will be filled out already*
string playersName = "";
...[Code]...

// How can I get the data[playerScore].name equal my playersName string?
cin.get (data[playerScore].name, 9);
// I know cin.get will be not in the code since I already get the players name with the string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy) member function, like

```
// length of the destination buffer so we won't overflow
size_t length = sizeof data[playerScore].name; 

// copy the string content to the char buffer
playersName.copy(data[playerScore].name, length);

// add the `'\0'` at the end
data[playerScore].name[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: `name` is a char array so it doesn't have a `size` method :)

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the one below? Is their any?

Comment: Also hmm I think the 2nd parameter of `.copy` is supposed to be the maximum amount it can ever copy to `name` (i.e. `sizeof(name)`)

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan This method is safer since it avoids overflowing `name`, thus avoiding security exploits.

Comment: What does the '\0' do at the end?

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan it's just using a different function (in this case, `std::string` member function). I'd say the other answer is more concise though. The `\0` at the end terminates the string, it is a convention used by C-like strings. The `strcpy` function automatically adds it though.

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan and yes, it is safer, since you cannot overflow (you should pass in the length of the destination buffer, see the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy). Thanks to thelink2012 for pointing this out.

Comment: The only thing about overflowing is I am a text limit, so I cannot input above 8 characters. So I don't think it would matter in my case, would it?

Comment: @vsoftco Nice :) Though you forgot the `.name` part here `sizeof data[playerScore]` :ddd

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan you should enforce that the user doesn't input more than 8 chars then. However, using the snippet above will assure you that *even if* more than 9 chars are input, the function doesn't copy more.

Comment: @vsoftco, I do enforce, if it goes above 8 characters, they won't be able to enter any more unless they delete previous one. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
strcpy(data[playerScore].name, playersName.c_str());
```

Comment: @vsoftco I'd not say so, `strcpy` may be prone to buffer overflows, mainly if used wrongly by begginers. I'd definitively say your answer is the way to go.

Comment: @thelink2012 I realized that now, thanks for pointing it out, I wasn't thinking about the overflow issue. Still keep my upvote though :)